# Error when Inserting or Updating Data using a column that is being created at "query / runtime time"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a deployment script that

1. Creates a new column with a default value of 0 and is Null-able
2. UPDATE the column data where a certain condition is met

Also note that if I explicitly set the default value to 0 in a INSERT Statement I recieve the same error when I am UPDATING data-

ERROR MESSAGE -

Invalid column name 'isConvertWithDivison'.

SQL I AM USING -

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.accountCurrencies 
    ADD isConvertWithDivison BIT NULL DEFAULT 0

UPDATE dbo.accountCurrencies SET  isConvertWithDivison = 1 WHERE  currencyName = 'USD'  

INSERT dbo.accountCurrencies 
        ( currencyName)
VALUES  ( 'AUD'),( 'DKK'),( 'RUB'),( 'SEK')
```

Seems Obvious what is going on but how do I work around this?

I have tried this to get the new collumn commited to the database before I execute the data changes but still no luck.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE dbo.accountCurrencies 
        ADD isConvertWithDivison BIT NULL DEFAULT 0
COMMIT TRANSACTION

UPDATE dbo.accountCurrencies SET  isConvertWithDivison = 1 WHERE  currencyName = 'USD'  

INSERT dbo.accountCurrencies 
        ( currencyName)
VALUES  ( 'AUD'),( 'DKK'),( 'RUB'),( 'SEK')
```

FYI - Running SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  [GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) after alter statement,

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.accountCurrencies 
    ADD isConvertWithDivison BIT NULL DEFAULT 0

go

UPDATE dbo.accountCurrencies SET  isConvertWithDivison = 1 WHERE  currencyName = 'USD'  

go
INSERT dbo.accountCurrencies 
        ( currencyName)
VALUES  ( 'AUD'),( 'DKK'),( 'RUB'),( 'SEK')
```